# Sublime Text SFTP with SecurID authentication

Tags: sublimetext2, sftp, sublimetext3

Sublime Text's SFTP works perfect with my work flow. I develop on my local computer, compile it on remote host mapped using sublime SFTP.

However, the new machine I'm working on uses SecurID for identification and Sublime's SFTP fails to connect. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com) does it flawlessly. Costly though ($49.5); so I'm planning to hack sshfs to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own Sublime Text plugin that does a similar thing.  Ask for support.  I analyzed this as deeply as I could, and I believe that the only problem is that the server responds with "Enter PASSCODE:".   As a former expect/perl's Expect  programmer, I think that is likely the only issue.